# JavaScript function not taking/setting form data

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I am writing a simple online order form for widgets which is supposed to take the order of 3 widgets, add them together and give a total number and a cost.  However, when the button is clicked to go into the function, nothing happens.  I am not sure whether the fault is in getting the data into the function or getting it out of the function.

```js
function cal() {
  var wid1 = document.getElementById("widg1").value;
  var wid2 = document.getElementById("widg2").value;
  var wid3 = document.getElementById("widg3").value;
  var tot = (wid1 + wid2 + wid3);
  var dollars = ((wid1 * 12.45) + (wid2 * 15.34) + (wid3 * 28.99));
  document.getElementByName("total").value = tot;
  document.getElementByName("money").value = dollars;
}
```

```html
<form name="widgets">
  widget model 37AX-L:<br>
  <input type="text" id="widg1" name="37AX-L" value=0><br> widget model 42XR-J:<br>
  <input type="text" id="widg2" name="42XR-J" value=0><br> widget model 93ZZ-A:<br>
  <input type="text" id="widg3" name="93ZZ-A" value=0><br>
  <br>
  <input type="button" name="B1" value="Calculate" onclick="cal()"><br>
</form>
<input type="text" name="total" id="total"> total widgets <br>
<input type="text" name="money" id="money"> total dollars
```

Comment: There's no function `getElementByName`, should be `getElementsByName`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**You omitted s in Elements.**

`document.getElementsByName("total")[0].value=tot` not `document.getElementByName("total")`

```html
<form name="widgets">
    widget model 37AX-L:<br>
    <input type="text" id="widg1" name="37AX-L"  value=0><br>
    widget model 42XR-J:<br>
    <input type="text" id="widg2" name="42XR-J"  value=0><br>
    widget model 93ZZ-A:<br>
    <input type="text" id="widg3" name="93ZZ-A"  value=0><br>
    <br>
    <input type="button" name="B1" value="Calculate" onclick="cal()"><br>
    </form>
    <input type="text" name="total" id="total"> total widgets <br>
    <input type="text" name="money" id="money"> total dollars
<script>
    function cal(){
        var wid1 = document.getElementById("widg1").value;
        var wid2 = document.getElementById("widg2").value;
        var wid3 = document.getElementById("widg3").value;
        var tot = (wid1+wid2+wid3);
        var dollars = ((wid1*12.45)+(wid2*15.34)+(wid3*28.99));
        document.getElementsByName("total")[0].value=tot;
        document.getElementsByName("money")[0].value=dollars;
    }
</script>
```